Why do I need to put the millis() function inside the main loop to trigger the ISR?
I'm trying to replicate that earbuds functionality that consists in a multifunctional button. If you press this button x amount of times, in a period of time, the earbud will do something depending on how many times you press the button.The problem is that I need to put millis() inside the main loop to trigger the ISR that increments the millis variable: ISR (TIMER0_COMPA_vect) and I don't understand why
These are my main code and libraries.
#include <mcu_init.h>
#include <millis.h>
#include <button.h>

int main() {

    GPIO_init();

    cli();

    INT0_init();
    TMR0_init();

    sei();

    while (1) {

        // If I put millis() here, ISR (TIMER0_COMPA_vect) starts triggering
        handleButton();
        
    }

    return 0;

}

#include <millis.h>

static volatile uint32_t miliseconds = 0;

ISR (TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {
    miliseconds++;
    PORTA |= (1 << 1);

}

uint32_t millis() {

    uint32_t time;
    uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;

    cli();

    time = miliseconds;
    SREG = oldSREG;

    return time;

}

This is the logic of the button, just in case.
#include <button.h>

volatile uint8_t count = 0;
volatile uint32_t lastPressTime = 0;

ISR (INT0_vect) {

    if (millis() - lastPressTime >= 200) {
        count++;
      lastPressTime = millis();

    }

}

void handleButton() {
  
  if (millis() - lastPressTime >= 1500) {
    lastPressTime = millis();

    switch (count) {

      case 2:
        PORTA ^= (1 << 1);
        count = 0;
        break;

      case 3:
        PORTA ^= (1 << 3);
        count = 0;
        break;

      default:
        count = 0;

    }

    }

    return;

}

These are the header files
#ifndef MILLIS_H_
#define MILLIS_H_

#include <avr/interrupt.h>

uint32_t millis();

#endif

#ifndef BUTTON_H_
#define BUTTON_H_

#include <millis.h>

void handleButton();

#endif


Please show [mre]s of all the code variants you want to discuss. "This works ... but why does this ... not work?" seems a more acceptable question than something containing "I tried everything", because you probably cannot imagine what users, e.g. one with 20+ years of professional embedded programming considers "everything" and that causes you and a potential valuable ally to talk about different things. Consider taking the [tour] and reading [ask].

You have to measure the time between debounced reads of the button.

You have explained what the code should do, but you have not described what it does do that is incorrect or actually asked a question.  It is a lot of code to wade through if you are not specific about what we are looking for.  Moreover rather than describing the code change that apparently makes it work, post that code too.

In your handleButton function, you reset the count variable every time you enter the if() block.
If you do not use the millis() function, i.e. you execute the switch() at every main loop, the count variable will probably be reset to zero again by the main as soon as your interrupt routine has incremented it from zero, has returned, and the main loop is executed again.
If you want to reset the variable count after a timeout occurs and no further press apart the first happens, you need to handle some states, like in the following code:
// as in your code, the minimum acceptable time between press events
#define def_click_debounce_ms 200
// after a press event occurs, if no more press events occur after this time, we assume that the user press sequence has completed
#define def_pause_validate_click_ms (def_click_debounce_ms + 1000)

// your ISR for the press event, just enriched with a signal on too short press
ISR (INT0_vect) {

    if (millis() - lastPressTime >= def_click_debounce_ms) {
        // increment the number of press detected
        count++;
        lastPressTime = millis();
    }
    else
    {
        // signal to main that an invalid press happened
        reset_wait_release_request++;
    }
}

// the status of handleButton check 
typedef enum _enum_check_button_press_status
{
    enum_check_button_press_status_init = 0,
    enum_check_button_press_status_check_press_sequence,
    enum_check_button_press_status_numof
}enum_check_button_press_status;

// our check button press status variable
enum_check_button_press_status e_check_button_press_status = enum_check_button_press_status_init;
// we use this variable to keep the number of press events handleButton detects
uint8_t num_consecutive_press_detected = 0;

void handleButton() {
    // store the current time
    const uint32_t now_ms = millis();
    switch(e_check_button_press_status)
    {
    case enum_check_button_press_status_init:
    default:
    {
        // no press detected at this moment
        num_consecutive_press_detected = 0;
        // check for a press sequence
        e_check_button_press_status = enum_check_button_press_status_check_press_sequence;
        break;
    }
    case enum_check_button_press_status_check_press_sequence:
    {
        // has the interrupt routine detected a new press?
        if (count != main_count)
        {
            // align our own press counter
            main_count = count;
            // increment the number of press detected by the main
            num_consecutive_press_detected++;
            // mark the time of the last press detected by the main
            start_wait_release_ms = now_ms;
        }
        // if an invalid press happened, let's restart our release timer
        else if (reset_wait_release_request != reset_wait_release_ack)
        {
            reset_wait_release_ack = reset_wait_release_request;
            // we restart the time of the last press detected by the main
            start_wait_release_ms = now_ms;
        }
        // if a timeout happens waiting for next press, let's check if it was a valid press sequence
        else if ((num_consecutive_press_detected > 0) && (now_ms - start_wait_release_ms >= def_pause_validate_click_ms))
        {
            // do your stuff
            switch(num_consecutive_press_detected)
            {
            case 0:
            {
                // should never happen...
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                // do the 2-clicks stuff
                PORTA ^= (1 << 1);
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                // do the 3-clicks stuff
                PORTA ^= (1 << 3);
                break;
            }
            
            case 1:
            default:
            {
                printf("Invalid number of press detected: %u\n", (unsigned int)num_consecutive_press_detected);
                break;
            }
            }
            
            // go back to the init state
            e_check_button_press_status = enum_check_button_press_status_init;
        }
        break;
    }
    }   

}


I can understand that part. But, how is my code entering the if block if the ISR is not triggering, so millis() is always equal to zero. I read the first comments and I tried to clarify my post and the question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Maybe if the int0 interrupt is level triggered, it could leave no room for the timer0 to be executed; could you please check your int0 setup?

I just commented out the INT0 Interrupt and tried it but TMR0 is not triggering yet.

I tried to turn on a led before debouncing the button on the ISR INT0, but it does not turn on. I mean, when I press the button it turns on several consecutive and fast times, but at the end it ends off. I can understand that this could happen if instead of turning on the led, I toggle it. But I'm just turning it on with PORTA |= (1 << 1);

I wonder if you would be so kind to post the INT0_init(); and TMR0_init(); code too

I was reviewing every part of the project and finally reached a solution. My IDE was compiling some dependencies directly from Arduino, such as wiring.c and hooks.c, which I didn't need to use in my project. These dependencies were interfering with my code, causing it to malfunction.

Thank you so much, man. That state machine was a great improvement to my code, and your questions kept me thinking, which was really good.

Mamy thanks to you! Have a nice day!
